# C# array member

Tags: c#, arrays

Here is my code and it gives red squiggly line under the variable of the array declaration, stating,

> Fixed size buffer fields may only be members of struct

float is a value type, so I don't quite understand this message.
What is the correct syntax to create public array of 13 elements (0 through 12; I ignore index 0)...

```
class clsUtility
{
    public int UtilityId { get; set; }
    public fixed float InterpolationFactorMonth[13];      // <-- HERE IS THE PROBLEM
}
```

Comment: The correct syntax is to declare it as an array of floats, and to allocate a 13-element array and assign to it, like this: `public float[] InterpolationFactorMonth = new float[13];`. As the error states, fixed arrays are only usable from structs, and usually only used with interop/marshalling scenarios where you need to pass the struct to some foreign unmanaged piece of code.

Comment: Lasse, yes.  if you post as answer I will accept that...I thought that the fact that it is only 13 elements means its fixed.  So fixed array is something else....

Comment: You already have a good answer by Jon, there's no need to create another one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want a fixed-sized array inline, that has to be declared within a struct, as per the compiler error. If you're *actually* happy with a reference to an array as normal, you need to differentiate between declaration and initialization. For example:

```cs
// Note: Utility isn't a great name either, but definitely lose the "cls" prefix.
class Utility
{
    public int UtilityId { get; set; }
    public float[] InterpolationFactorMonth { get; } = new float[13];
}
```

This declares a read-only property of type `float[]`, and initializes it with a new array of 13 elements.

Answer (score 2):

So first of all, it is not possible to use `fixed` in this case. 
You could use `public float[] InterpolationFactorMonth = new float[13];` 
To create an array of the size 13.

Comment: It is possible to use fixed for arrays, just not in classes.

Comment: Please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers - fixed size buffers definitely do exist. They're not quite the same as a regular array, but they use the same syntax, hence the error message the OP is seeing.